# select query issue selects value with undefined

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query like

```
select * from jobs where (minexp >=0 and maxexp <=12)
```

where minexp and maxexp are varchar(5) and and default As defined (I have given nothing here)

the problem is, it selects rows with minexp 0 and maxexp nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the fields `minexp` and `maxexp` only supposed to contain integers, why create the fields as varchar? This is probably why your query is returning invalid results. Try changing the field type to `int` and try the same query again.

Comment: Are there any rows in that range? Show us sample data too

Comment: I could be wrong but what I think is happening is that your minexp and maxexp are in one set of brackets, so it may be that it's prioritizing the minexp... do a little test, switch the maxexp and minexp around and see what result you get...

Comment: I just rectified problem with adding one more and select * from jobs where (minexp >=0 and maxexp <=12 and maxexp != '')  Thanks for all your help bro's

Comment: why don't you have a single field like "Experience" and run your query like
`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE Experience between 0 and 12;` or `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE Experience >0 AND Experience < 12;`